# How do I add a module to pip install in gitlab.ci pipeline

Tags: python, github, flask, gitlab, gitlab-ci

when I run my gitlab-ci pipeline:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

COPY ./requirement.txt /app/requirement.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt
COPY ./src /app

EXPOSE 8006

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

**CI file**

```
image: ubuntu:18.04
stages:
    - test
test:
    stage: test
    script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
    - cd src
    - python3 -m unittest test
```

I get this error during the test stage:

```
Some modules are missing, no module named 'requests'
```

I thought that requests were a default module, I was wrong.
So I added it to the `requirements.txt` file:

**requirements.txt**

[image: requirements.txt]

I re-ran the tests and got the same issue.

Comment: you're running a ci pipeline or docker build? The file above looks like a Dockerfile. If what you're trying to do is a ci pipeline, kindly post the ci.yaml file.

Comment: @OlasimboArigbabu Have added now , apologies

Comment: you need to install your `requirements.txt` in your ci pipeline. The `.yaml` is basically running a job, it still needs to know your environment and dependencies. I hope that helps. Example: https://github.com/ginomempin/sample-ci-python/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml